# ¿Cómo insertar una imagen en C# y convertirla en bytes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, blob

Estoy haciendo un programa que ya tiene tablas, inserto datos desde una base de datos a otra.En esta recupero una ruta hacia directorios donde se encuentran imagenes pero estas las quiero convertir en bytes y subirlas a  mi base de datos.
Mi columna que tendra esta imagen se llama fst135_docbyte y la que tiene la ruta fst135_rutadoc.

Ya recupero los bytes y si me muestra los mismos de la imagen pero no me lo inserta en la tabla.

Les comparto mi codigo en c# .net en wcf esta mi codigo.

```
public List<CInvesdoc> plistObtenerDatosGuias(string lsrMaster, string lsrHouse, string lsrRegistro)
        {

            DataTable dt = gconexionDatos.plistObtenerDatosGuias(lsrMaster, lsrHouse, lsrRegistro);
            List<CInvesdoc> list = new List<CInvesdoc>();
            CDocumento doc = new CDocumento();

            

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {

                CInvesdoc u = new CInvesdoc();
                CGuia g = new CGuia();
                g.lsrFst136_IdExpediente = dr["Fst136_IdExpediente"].ToString();
                g.lsrFst136_GMaster = dr["Fst136_GMaster"].ToString();
                g.lsrFst136_GHouse = dr["Fst136_GHouse"].ToString();
                g.lsrFst136_Registro = dr["Fst136_Registro"].ToString();
                g.lsrFst136_NameTipoExpediente = dr["Fst136_NameTipoExpediente"].ToString();

                CDocumento d = new CDocumento();
                //d.lsrFst135_IdDocumento = dr["Fst135_IdDocumento"].ToString();
                d.lsrFst136_IdExpediente = dr["Fst136_IdExpediente"].ToString();
                d.lsrFst135_RutaDoc = dr["Fst135_RutaDoc"].ToString();
                //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myString);
                //if (dr["FST135_DocByte"] != DBNull.Value)
                //    d.lsrFst135_DocByte = (byte[])dr["FST135_DocByte"];
                //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr["FST135_DocByte"].ToString());

                

                bool Resp = false;
                string ruta = $@"\{d.lsrFst135_RutaDoc}";
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                Resp = File.Exists(ruta);

                if (Resp)
                {
                    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta);
                    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta);
                    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr["FST135_DocByte"].ToString());
                    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = File.ReadAllBytes(ruta); 
                    //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta);
                    //foreach (byte bytes in byteArray)
                    //{
                    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta);
                    //byte[] lsrFst135_DocByte = new byte[ruta.Length];
                    //for (int i = 0; i < ruta.Length; i++)
                    //{
                    //    lsrFst135_DocByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(ruta[i]);
                    //}

                    d.lsrFst135_DocByte = File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
                    //foreach (var f in files)
                    //{
                    //    Stream fs1 = null;
                    //    BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
                    //    d.lsrFst135_DocByte = br1.ReadBytes((Int32)fs1.Length);

                    //    //d.lsrFst135_DocByte = File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
                    //    //ruta = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(d.lsrFst135_DocByte); 
                    //}
                    //byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ruta); 
                    //ticket.Content = File.ReadAllBytes(ticket.Ruta);
                    //BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
                    //byteFile = br1.ReadBytes((Int32)fs1.Length);
                    //if (dr["FST135_DocByte"] != DBNull.Value) 
                    //    byteArray = (byte[])dr["FST135_DocByte"];
                    //byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr["FST135_DocByte"].ToString());
                    //byte[] r = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr["FST135_DocByte"].ToString());
                    //}

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("No existe");
                }

                u.CDocumento = d;
                u.CGuia = g;
                list.Add(u);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

y mi base de datos mi procedure esta de la siguiente manera , espero me puedan apoyar en que linea estoy mal o que me falta .

```
PROCEDURE Sp_ConsultaInsertarDatos(pfld2 VARCHAR2, pfld3 VARCHAR2, pfld1 VARCHAR2, saldatos_cursor  OUT datos_cursor) IS
                            
   sal_cursor datos_cursor;   
   fechaActual DATE;
   v_existe number(10);
   Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE varchar2(25 byte) ;    
   Sec_fst135_iddocumento varchar2(25 byte) ;  
    
    CURSOR c_sec IS
    
    SELECT 'EXP-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM') || TRIM(TO_CHAR(SEC_GUIAINVESDOC.NEXTVAL, '9999999999')) INTO Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE FROM DUAL;--
    --WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM FST136_GUIASINVESDOC WHERE  FST136_GHOUSE = FST136_GHOUSE AND FST136_RUTADOC = FST136_RUTADOC) ;
    
    CURSOR c_sec2 IS
    SELECT 'DOC-' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM') || TRIM(TO_CHAR(SEC_DOCINVESDOC.NEXTVAL, '9999999999')) INTO Sec_fst135_iddocumento FROM DUAL; 
        
    
    BEGIN
       
        SELECT sysdate into fechaActual from dual;       
                                                                                   
    DECLARE
            
            CURSOR c_ConsultaGuias IS
            SELECT DISTINCT rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.name TIPO, fld2 MASTER, fld3 HOUSE, rinves11.A20SF.fld1 REGISTRO
            FROM rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR@INVESDOC 
            INNER JOIN rinves11.A20SF@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.extid2 = rinves11.A20SF.fdrid
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.volid  = rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.id
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLREPHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.repid = rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.id
            WHERE fld2 = NVL('',fld2) AND fld3 = NVL('SZX833478', fld3) AND  fld1 = NVL('', fld1);
                                                   
            CURSOR c_ConsultaDatos IS 
            SELECT
            dbms_lob.substr@INVESDOC((SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.info, '"01.01"|"\\Srv-invest', '\192.170.1.103'),'"01.01"|"\\srv-invest','\192.170.1.103'),'"01.01"|"\',''),'"01.01"|"\\192.170.1.104',''),'"01.01"|"',''),'"|3|1|3|0|0',''),'"|3|2|3|0|0','') || '\' || rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.name || '\' || rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.loc 
            FROM dual@INVESDOC), 4000, 1) AS INFO
            FROM rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR@INVESDOC 
            INNER JOIN rinves11.A20SF@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.extid2 = rinves11.A20SF.fdrid
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLFILEHDR.volid  = rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.id
            INNER JOIN rinves11.IVOLREPHDR@INVESDOC  ON rinves11.IVOLVOLHDR.repid = rinves11.IVOLREPHDR.id
            WHERE fld2 = NVL(pfld2,fld2) AND fld3 = NVL(pfld3, fld3) AND  fld1 = NVL(pfld1, fld1);

            CURSOR c_Datos IS 
            SELECT FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE, FST136_NAMETIPOEXPEDIENTE, FST136_GMASTER, FST136_GHOUSE, FST136_REGISTRO, FST136_USUARIOCREACION, FST136_FECHACREACION 
            FROM FST136_GUIASINVESDOC ORDER BY fst136_ghouse,fst136_idexpediente ASC;
            --WHERE EXISTS(SELECT fst136_idexpediente, FST136_GHOUSE, FST136_RUTADOC FROM FST136_GUIASINVESDOC WHERE FST136_GHOUSE=FST136_GHOUSE AND FST136_RUTADOC=FST136_RUTADOC);
            
    --BEGIN    
    --     FOR r_Datos IN c_Datos LOOP 
    --     SELECT count(*) into v_existe from FST136_GUIASINVESDOC where FST136_GHOUSE= r_Datos.FST136_GHOUSE;
     --    END LOOP;
    --COMMIT;
    
    BEGIN  
    
    --FOR r_Datos IN c_Datos LOOP 
     --  IF (r_Datos.FST136_GMASTER > 1) AND (r_Datos.FST136_GHOUSE > 1) THEN
     --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ya se encuentra registrado');
     --  END IF;
    --END LOOP;
     
     --IF v_existe = 0 THEN
       FOR r_Columna IN c_ConsultaGuias LOOP 
  
           OPEN  c_sec;
           FETCH c_sec INTO Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE;
           IF c_sec%notfound THEN EXIT;
           END IF;
           CLOSE   c_sec;
       
       INSERT INTO FST136_GUIASINVESDOC(FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE,FST136_NAMETIPOEXPEDIENTE, FST136_GMASTER,FST136_GHOUSE,FST136_REGISTRO, FST136_USUARIOCREACION,FST136_FECHACREACION)--,FST136_RUTADOC)
       VALUES (Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE ,r_Columna.TIPO , r_Columna.MASTER,r_Columna.HOUSE,r_Columna.REGISTRO,'JEMARTINEZ', SYSDATE);--,r_Columna.INFO);

       END LOOP;
       
       FOR r_Columna IN c_ConsultaDatos LOOP 
       
        OPEN  c_sec2;
           FETCH c_sec2 INTO Sec_fst135_iddocumento;
           IF c_sec2%notfound THEN EXIT;
           END IF;
           CLOSE   c_sec2;
        
        INSERT INTO FST135_INVESDOCUMENTOS (FST135_IDDOCUMENTO,FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE,FST135_RUTADOC,FST135_DOCBYTE) 
        VALUES(Sec_fst135_iddocumento,Sec_FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE,r_Columna.INFO, EMPTY_BLOB());
        
       END LOOP;
     
     COMMIT;
    
    -- ELSE
     --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ya se encuentra registrado');
     --END IF;
    
    --ELSE
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ya se encuentra registrado');

    --BEGIN
       --FOR r_Columna IN c_ActualizaDatos LOOP 
      -- UPDATE  FST136_GUIASINVESDOC SET FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE=r_Columna.FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE WHERE FST136_GHOUSE=r_Columna.FST136_GHOUSE;
       --END LOOP;
    --COMMIT;
    
    OPEN sal_cursor FOR
    
    SELECT fst135_iddocumento,fst136_guiasinvesdoc.fst136_idexpediente, fst136_nametipoexpediente,fst136_gmaster,fst136_ghouse,fst136_registro,fst135_rutadoc,fst135_docbyte
    FROM fst136_guiasinvesdoc
    INNER JOIN fst135_invesdocumentos ON  fst136_guiasinvesdoc.FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE = fst135_invesdocumentos.FST136_IDEXPEDIENTE;
    saldatos_cursor := sal_cursor; 

    END;
    --END;
      

END Sp_ConsultaInsertarDatos;
```

Comment: Porque querrias guardar una imagen que ya esta guardada, en otro lugar donde luego para usarla vas a tener que volver a transformarla? mas alla de eso, que quiere decir que no inserta? hay algun error?

Comment: Bueno realmente es un requerimiento que me pidieron yo no decido. Si al momento de ir y buscar la ruta esta imagen debe convertirse en bytes y subirse en el campo blob pero supongo que por el empty_blob() me sube este o no este el documento, quiero creer. Y pues no puedo visualizar un error por lo anterior.La imagen esta en carpetas y se desea hacer respaldo en la base de datos .

Comment: Vi unas imagenes que tenian aqui y me marcaban longitud osea me daba que tenia algo no se 13435 longitud y con las q subo me marcan en 0, no se si porque se sube desde c# aqui es necesario regresarla(deserializar o convertirla nuevamente en imagen) para ver si , si guardo